# load xml files from jars when wildcards in spring

Tags: spring-3

**Overview of Scenario** 
we are in a application(Spring && REST) where there are large number of module in the form of JARs and each module has its context loader && classpath. So here I want to load some XMLs from sub module but what is happening, I am not able to load any xml from JAR.

**What I am doing?**
I am using the below code to fetch the xmls from sub module JAR but it is not reading context loader from submodule. According to my understanding it should load all the xmls from with the the application but the same is not happening.

**Code Snippet**

```xml
<bean id="mapper" class="org.dozer.spring.DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="mappingFiles">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:*mappings.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**What is the expectation?**
I want to load all the xmls from sub module in a single go, so that I need not explicitly call each and every mapping file in root context loader.

Thanks in advanced.